# locastorage and tabs menu on ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, ionic3

I have a map on tabs1.

I click the marker and sending localstorage markers title and sending to tab2. Thats work good.

```
that.passingData(dogwalkMarker.valueOf().parkid);

passingData(something: string) {
localStorage.setItem('passingData', JSON.stringify(something));
console.log(something);
```

But when i first load the tab2 following return something goes wrong. After i load any page on app and load tab 2 back it works and return good!

I dont understand where am i doing mistake. Thanks.

i have following codes on tabs 2 .

```
scanOtopark() {
this.selectedOtopark = {};
let x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('passingData'));

this.selectedOtopark = this.otoparks.find(otopark => otopark.parkqr === x);
if (this.selectedOtopark !== undefined) {
  this.otoparkFound = true;

  const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: "good",
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });
  toast.present();
  console.log(this.selectedOtopark);
} else {
  this.otoparkFound = false;
  const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'something goes wrong',
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });
  toast.present();
  this.selectedOtopark = {};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

That was my fault beacuse i defined my getting database codes inside constructor. Because of that page needs to load for getting datas.

**forgotten code part**

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          private storageCtrl: Storage,
          private platformCtrl: Platform,
          ) {

this.firebaseProvider.getOtoparks().subscribe((response) => {
  this.otoparks = response;
  console.log(this.otoparks);
});}
```

So i import that code inside the function and it works!

**tab1**

```
passingData(something: string) {
this.platformCtrl.ready().then(() => {
  this.storageCtrl.set('passingData', something);
  console.log(something);
});
```

**tab2**

```
passingData: any;
scanOtopark() {
this.platformCtrl.ready().then(() => {
  this.storageCtrl.get('passingData').then((data) => {
    this.passingData = data;
    this.firebaseProvider.getOtoparks().subscribe((response) => {
      this.otoparks = response;
      this.selectedOtopark = this.otoparks.find(otopark => otopark.parkqr === this.passingData);

      if (this.selectedOtopark !== undefined) {
        this.otoparkFound = true;
        console.log(this.selectedOtopark);


        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: "good",
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();
      } else {
        this.otoparkFound = false;
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'something goes wrong',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    });
  });
});}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an `async` issue with your local storage.So I highly recommend using [**native storage module**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). Since it supports promises out of the box you can easily use it on `async` situations.And it works correctly on all the platforms if you install SQLite too (especially `iOS` device this is needed.)

*Example from the doc:*

```
 // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
```

**Update:**

On `first time load` you need to use :

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    });
```

**Update 2:**

```
x: any;

scanOtopark() {
this.selectedOtopark = {};


this.platformCtrl.ready().then(() => {
  this.storageCtrl.get('passingData').then((data) => {
    this.x= data;

  this.selectedOtopark = this.otoparks.find(otopark => otopark.parkqr === this.x);
  if (this.selectedOtopark !== undefined) {
    this.otoparkFound = true;

    const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "good",
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
    console.log(this.selectedOtopark);
  } else {
    this.otoparkFound = false;
    const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'something goes wrong',
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
    this.selectedOtopark = {};
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hello. @Sampath I tried this. But it still goes wrong with the same problem. `this.storageCtrl.get('passingData').then((data) => {
      this.x= data;
      console.log(data);
    });
`

Comment: See the **Update**.

Comment: i copy all of my code inside `this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    });` but does not work.

Comment: Can you show the `last code` change? Put it under your question.

Comment: Where you used this `this.x= data;`?

Comment: oh sorry edited again... `this.selectedOtopark = this.otoparks.find(otopark => otopark.parkqr === this.x);
`

Comment: You cannot work like that with the `async` or `promise`. You need to put everything inside the `this.storageCtrl.get('passingData').then((data) => {` See **Update 2**

Comment: i tried that. does not change anything... still when i click tab1 and load the tab2  gives error `something goes wrong`

Comment: You need to test this on the device.

Comment: same on device.

Comment: What is the error? What is the value of this `this.x` at runtime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156796/discussion-between-onurkaya-and-sampath).